# Google Map Get Direction Search Algorithm

Tags: android, algorithm, search, google-maps, shortest-path

I learned that Google Map has a Get Direction feature that let users find the shortest path from one point to another. What search algorithm did Google used for this search? Is this algorithm can be implemented in the Android platform, knowing that it has low memory and it's running in Java(tend to be slow)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that they use either A* (A-star) or dijkstra's algorithm. 
Comparing the two, A* uses less memory and thus is more likely that they use a hybrid of that.

Comment: I think so too. But I need to have a backup document. Do you know where can I get a proof that they use the A* search for the Get Directions feature?

Comment: Mmm, what about asking Google?

Comment: Can I really do that? wow. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it later ^^